# Changing dns domain name in Kali

Tags: kali-linux

I was having an issue changing the "dnsdomainname" after installing Kali. Usually I would set it from the beginning of it's installation. However I used used the vdi from the website and it comes with it's default blank domain name.

Comment: Answers should be split out into the answer box, please & thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller My apologies, I will try to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through some files and comparing my machine with another one containing a different domain name, I managed to find a way to change the domain name.

In case the dnsdomainname is blank or none the second line in the `/etc/hosts` will be like:

```
x.x.x.x   yourhostname
```

Change the second line so it looks like this:

```
x.x.x.x  yourhostname.yourdnsdomainname  yourhostname
```

You can then check the dns domain name in the terminal with the commmand `dnsdomainname` and it'll return the domain name you set.